# MySQL JOIN get non existing rows

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables:

IMMAGINI (Italian for "images"):

```
| id_img | id_immobile | id_utente | img_url |    type | visible_website | visible_pdf | pdf_img_type | category |
|--------|-------------|-----------|---------|---------|-----------------|-------------|--------------|----------|
|      3 |           1 |         0 |   1.jpg | general |               1 |           1 |         foto |     foto |
```

IMMOBILI (Italian for "real estate properties"):

```
| id_immobile | type | id_utente |
|-------------|------|-----------|
|           1 | demo |        90 |
```

(this is not the full table, but we don't need it all for this)

In my application model I need to list all of the `immobili` rows base on certain conditions.

The problem I'm trying to solve is that, I need the list of all `immobili` and I do join it with images based on the "id_immobile" field key.

The images I need from the `immagini` table is only the one which has a `type` value of `main`. If there is no `main` type then I STILL NEED the `immobili`row to show up but the `img_url` should return `NULL`.

So my current query is:

```
SELECT
immobili.id_immobile,
CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(immagini.img_url, ".", 1), "_thumb.", SUBSTRING_INDEX(immagini.img_url, ".", -1)) as img
FROM immobili    
LEFT JOIN immagini
on immagini.id_immobile = immobili.id_immobile    
WHERE (immagini.type = "main" OR immagini.type = "general" OR immagini.type IS NULL)
GROUP BY immobili.id_immobile
ORDER BY immobili.data_inserimento DESC, immobili.data_aggiornamento DESC
```

With this query I get all the above working on, BUT if the `immagini` table is empty or does not have a `main` type, THE WHOLE `immobile` line is not shown (returns 0 rows).

The result I want is to show all of the `immobili` rows anyways and show a `NULL` `img_url` if there are no matching rows.

Comment: I don't see how this is not working. Are you sure you are showing the real query? A typical error is to mistakenly dismiss outer-joined records in the `WHERE` clause, but this is not the case in your query, because you allow for `immagini.type IS NULL`. (I would move the conditions to the `ON` clause anyway for readability.)

Comment: I don't really see the use of `GROUP BY immobili.id_immobile`. Are you trying to limit your `immagini` matches to one row? This method is not allowed in Standard SQL, but MySQL will probably return a matching row arbitrarily picked (i.e. you may either get the main img or a general img; which you can't know). At last you are ordering your rows by columns that don't exist in the result. This is invalid SQL again, leading to an arbitrary sort order in MySQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove where clause and move your criteria in `on` clause so that only rows get joined from `immagini` which satisfies your criteria, If you have any filters for `immobili` then use where clause

```
SELECT
immobili.id_immobile,
CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(immagini.img_url, ".", 1), "_thumb.", SUBSTRING_INDEX(immagini.img_url, ".", -1)) as img
FROM immobili    
LEFT JOIN immagini
ON immagini.id_immobile = immobili.id_immobile    
AND immagini.type = "main"
GROUP BY immobili.id_immobile
ORDER BY immobili.data_inserimento DESC, immobili.data_aggiornamento DESC
```

Comment: using OR  on join condition is large tables are very costly !!!! huge !!!!

Comment: Actually I removed the "OR" as I only need "main" images and this works great

Comment: A GROUP BY clause with no aggregating functions is never going to end well.

Answer (score 3):

The problem with your query is the restriction you have in the `WHERE` clause.  It is filtering off records entirely.  The usual way to fix this is to move the `WHERE` logic into the `ON` clause:

```
SELECT
    i.id_immobile,
    CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(im.img_url, '.', 1), '_thumb.',
        SUBSTRING_INDEX(im.img_url, '.', -1)) AS img
FROM immobili i  
LEFT JOIN immagini im
    ON i.id_immobile = im.id_immobile AND im.type IN ('main', 'general')
ORDER BY
    i.data_inserimento DESC,
    i.data_aggiornamento DESC;
```

Note that I removed the `GROUP BY` clause because your select does not actually use any aggregates.  Based on your data, the above query makes sense.  Perhaps you intended to use `GROUP_CONCAT`, but we would need to see some data to confirm this.

Comment: How does `WHERE (… OR immagini.type IS NULL)` filter off outer-joined rows? I don't see this happening.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner This was the OP's attempt to counter the effects of the `WHERE` clause.  What I'm conjecturing is that the OP doesn't really want those `NULL` rows.